# Relace a string in a set of strings - regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I replace a string in a long string like below using regex (JS) please?

My string could be one of the following:

```
str = "this may have bgskin-akb4c hello how";
or
str = "have bgskin-a2b3c hello";
or
str = "bgskin-xyz2 hello";
or 
str = "bgskin-bbc";
```

in the above string I would like to replace the 2nd part of the word (ex: -akb4c, -xyz2) starting with "bgskin" with a new string value, ex: **"have bgskin-a2b3c hello"** becomes **"have bgskin-newstr hello"**

Appreciate your help on this.

Many thanks,
L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript

```
str.replace(/bgskin-\w+/g, 'bgskin-newstr');
```

Comment: Although, it wasn't explicitly stated in the question, your code will only replace the first occurring of the pattern. You need to add the global flag to the pattern.

Comment: Thanks a ton => eduardocereto :) That worked like a charm for my situation!

Comment: I added the global flag as proposed by @jessegavin

Answer (score 1):

The `gi` flags at the end of my regex pattern tell it to do a global and case-insensitive search.

```
var pattern = /bgskin-[a-z0-9]+/gi;
str.replace(pattern, "bgskin-newstr");
```

**See it working on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VMtnW/**

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "this may have bgskin-akb4c hello how";
var newstr = str.replace(/(bgskin-)[^\s]+/gi, "$1test");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, assuming you always want the replacement string to be the same: `s/bgskin-\w+/bgskin-newstr/g`